# Generate new openssl.cnf

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to renew my SSL certificate following this guide https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9446/14/generating-csr-on-apache-opensslmodsslnginx-heroku/

The command `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr` tells me:

```
unable to find 'distinguished_name' in config
problems making Certificate Request
140339049886848:error:0E06D06A:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no conf or environment variable:../crypto/conf/conf_lib.c:270:
```

I can't find the `openssl.cnf` file in any of the locations mentioned online so I'd like to generate a new one.

Reinstalling openssl didn't help and I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: Have you searched for `openssl.cfg` or `openssl.ini` ?  Regardless, create a simple configuration file for your server cert request, and specify the `-config server.cnf` argument in your `openssl req` command-line.  No real need to regenerate openssl.cnf, if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the openssl.cnf file, locate the directory where openssl was being installed.
Open the bin folder and open the cnf folder.
Within the cnf folder/directory, you will find the openssl.cnf file